# ibm cognos перекрестная таблица

Tags: sql

всех. в report studio в перекрестной таблице не отображатся данные в строковом столбце, хотя в бд данные есть, данные вытаскиваю через собственный sql-запрос. подскажите как можно решить проблему? я новичок в этом деле

Comment: как минимум покажите что у вас за запрос и структуру данных

Comment: SELECT  
r.pos rwnum,
MAX (CASE c.pos WHEN 1 THEN a.data ELSE NULL END) C1,
MAX (CASE c.pos WHEN 5 THEN NVL2(a.CDATA,TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(A.CDATA,0,1000)),A.DATA) ELSE NULL END) С5
FROM      monitoring.op_crosstabdata a 
       INNER JOIN 
        monitoring.ref_report_row r 
       ON a.idreport = r.idreport AND a.rwnum = r.idrow 
      INNER JOIN 
       monitoring.ref_report_column c 
      ON a.idreport = c.idreport AND a.colnum = c.idcolumn

Comment: столбец C5 строковый, в свойствах элемента указана функция агрегации - нет, агрегатная функция объединения - нет